# Will a 6+2-pin PCI-E plug work in place of an 8-pin EPS12V plug?

Tags: hardware, power-supply-unit

The motherboard I'm looking to get has a 24pin and 2x 8pin connectors on it. The power supply has a 24pin, 8pin, 4pin, 6pin and a 6+2pin connector. Will this work correctly or should I look for a power supply with 2x 8pin connectors on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are adapter cables such as this [Startech](http://www.pricebat.ca/STARTECH-EPS48ADAP-6IN-4-TO-8-PIN-EPS-POWER-WITH-LP4-CABLE-ADAPTER-F-M-RETAIL.p_10108211/) cable.

Having said that, I would get a PSU that has the proper cables built-in due to a correct PSU having enough amps on the correct rails, etc.